# Table: One column percentage and the rest should be split equal

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I try to have one column 30% of \textwidth and the rest should split equally. I achieved this, but it always destroys my table if I have the values in the table centered (left column should be left aligned). The last `>{\centering}X` is the issue. Column d is the problem

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Target}
\label{tab:target}
\begin{tabularx}{ \textwidth}{>{\hsize=.2\textwidth }X >{\centering}X >{\centering}X >{\centering}X >{\centering}X}

    \multirow{2}{*}{Model year} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Parameters}\\\cline{2-5}
    & a & b & c & d\\
    \hline
    2012 & 35.95 & 27.95 & 0.0005308 & 0.006057 \\
    2013 & 36.80 & 28.46 & 0.0005308 & 0.005410 \\
    2014 & 37.75 & 29.03 & 0.0005308 & 0.004725 \\
    2015 & 39.24 & 29.90 & 0.0005308 & 0.003719 \\
    2016 & 41.09 & 30.96 & 0.0005308 & 0.002573 \\
\end{tabularx} \end{table}
```

Is there a way how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest fix is to replace

```
>{\centering}X
```

in the final column with

```
>{\centering\arraybackslash}X
```

You may also want to consider generating better-spaced horizontal lines using `\midrule` and `\cmidrule` (provided by the `booktabs` package) instead of `\hline` and `\cline`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,caption}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Target}
\label{tab:target}
\begin{tabularx}{ \textwidth}{l CCCC}
Model year & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Parameters}\\
\cmidrule(l){2-5}
    & a & b & c & d\\
    \midrule
    2012 & 35.95 & 27.95 & 0.0005308 & 0.006057 \\
    2013 & 36.80 & 28.46 & 0.0005308 & 0.005410 \\
    2014 & 37.75 & 29.03 & 0.0005308 & 0.004725 \\
    2015 & 39.24 & 29.90 & 0.0005308 & 0.003719 \\
    2016 & 41.09 & 30.96 & 0.0005308 & 0.002573 \\
\end{tabularx} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In my opinion, the head of the 1st column would be nicer if in the 2nd row. No multirow required for that!

Comment: @Bernard - I guess we will need to agree to disagree on this subject. :-) In my view, "Model Year" is of the same general importance as "Parameters". Placing it a row lower down, level with "a", "b", "c", and "d", risks creating a false (visual) impression. Obviously, this is to a large degree a matter of taste, and *de gustibus non est disputandum*...